# Safari in Windows 7 64-bit won't start

Tags: safari-windows

When I go to start Safari on Windows 7 64-bit, I get an error dialog box:

```
Your copy of Safari is missing important software resources. Please reinstall Safari.
```

I deleted the Apple Application Support and the Apple Software Update.  I refuse to have these two pieces installed. I do not need any program giving me support or auto updates.  Safari works just fine without them in XP.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can get by without the Application Support app? Try reinstalling Safari and see if you still have the issue with Application Support installed. (Then, if you want, uninstall that and see if Safari still works.)

Since you don't have the updater installed, you should check regularly to see if there are new versions of Safari so you don't get hit with some known exploit.

Comment: Hit with a know exploit? Don't buy into that. Auto Updates should never be on if you want your computer to run optimal.  It's just junk littering your computer. Anyways, I want to know of a work around for Safari working without these two programs.

Comment: "Auto Updates should never be on if you want your computer to run optimal. It's just junk littering your computer." That's a pretty silly thing to say. Try attending a BlackHat conference.

Comment: I manually update all of my programs. It is ridiculous to have every program installed to have extra programs to run in the background to check for updates.  They are all resource hogs. It's pointless to have a program running all the time to just check for an update to that program. It's not for safety...it's for them to have their program more embedded into your computer.

Comment: @picxelplay I agree with you about the all the little update programs being stupid, but, ultimately, OS- and browser-level updates should be automatic. (Though Chrome and Firefox's methods are better than Apple's Software Update dingus.)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your anti-virus software and/or a lack of proper administrator privileges is preventing Safari from being installed correctly?

Try disabling them temporarily and doing a re-install.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run Safari on Windows 10, just downloaded version 5.1 which works just perfect. The previous 5.0 didn't start at all with `Your copy of Safari is missing important software resources. Please reinstall Safari`.