# Why won't my Safari open?

Tags: safari, macos

When I try to open safari it says:

> The procedure entry point sqlite3_wal_checkpoint could not be located in the dynamic link library SQLite3dll.

then it says:

> Your copy of safari is missing important software resources. Please re-install safari.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be having the same issue [discussed in this Stack Exchange answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/safari-in-windows-7-64-bit-wont-start) from a few years ago.

Re-download Safari using the link in [this support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531), and try re-installing it. Note that Apple [appears to be winding down Safari for Windows](http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/19/farewell-windows-safari-as-apple-excludes-from-icloud-bookmark-sync/).